# TVVLCKit Implementation SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, libvlc

I need to implement the VLC library in one of my TVOS applications, what I have currently is the following:

```
import SwiftUI
import TVVLCKit

struct VlcPlayerDemo: UIViewRepresentable{
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<VlcPlayerDemo>) {
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        return PlayerUIView(frame: .zero)
    }
}

class PlayerUIView: UIView, VLCMediaPlayerDelegate {
  private let mediaPlayer = VLCMediaPlayer()

  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    let url = URL(string: "URL")!

    mediaPlayer.media = VLCMedia(url: url)
    mediaPlayer.delegate = self
    mediaPlayer.drawable = self
    mediaPlayer.play()
  }

  required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }

  override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
  }
}
```

This code works and plays the content correctly, but I need to play it in full screen and have controls to pause, play and track selectors as AVPlayer has them.

[image: AVPlayer Example]

Comment: have you looked at official samples and the vlc iOS app?

Comment: Yes, but they don't  have an implementation of SwiftUi

Comment: You need to implement the playback / track selector UI yourself. There is no prebuilt UI in VLCKit. It should be possible to do that in swiftui. For fullscreen, you need configure the video output view to have the dimensions of your screen. This should also be possible in swiftui.

Comment: that is not helpful, "you need to do it yourself, it's possible in swiftui" is not helping or answering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all you have to do is add a ZStack layer on-top of the VLC player and add your info and interactions there,

i have a written a full working code example with TVVLCKit and SwiftUI fro Apple-Tv on github that demonstrate how to add play pause and thumbmail control, a metadata info panel (as a place holder you can fill there what ever you want)

https://github.com/shaybc/VLCTester

hope this help more